# DataGridView C# проверка на ввод данных в ячейке

Tags: c#, datagridview

Прошу помощи. Есть DataGridView и я пытаюсь реализовать проверку строки при вводе текста в ячейку. Пока нашел только как получать нажатые символы:

```
private void MyDataGridSpace_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
        tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tb_KeyPress);
    }

    void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = testingEnterChar(sender as TextBox, e.KeyChar);
    }
```

Но мне нужно получать целую строку в процессе набора для поиска и пока никак не найду решение.

Comment: а если подписаться на событие LostFocus и проверять содержимое после окончания ввода?

Comment: `(sender as TextBox).Text`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tb.KeyPress +=` вы подписываетесь на событие, но не отписываетесь, это приведет к глюкам и утечкам памяти. Ну используйте свойство `TextBox.Text`.

Правильная реализация будет выглядеть вот так:

```cs
private DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl currentEditingControl;

private void MyDataGridSpace_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentEditingControl != null)
    {
        currentEditingControl.KeyPress -= EditingControl_KeyPress;
        currentEditingControl = null;
    }
}

private void MyDataGridSpace_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentEditingControl == null && e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb)
    {
        currentEditingControl = tb;
        currentEditingControl.KeyPress += EditingControl_KeyPress;
    }
}

private void EditingControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb)
    {
        e.Handled = testingEnterChar(tb.Text, e.KeyChar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно обрабатывать событие [OnCellEndEdit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncellendedit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_OnCellEndEdit_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellEventArgs_). В аргументах события Вы найдёте `RowIndex` (`e.RowIndex`). По нему Вы сможет получить остальные ячейки строки для проверки.

Если нужно получать данные на "лету", придётся стоит обратить внимание на  OnCellBwginEdit и обработать что-то наподобие OnKeyPress.

Comment: OnCellEndEdit срабатывает по завершению ввода, а мне нужно именно в процессе набора текста получать полную строку которая набрана.

Comment: Тогда придётся обработать ещё 1 или 2 события, т.к. в OnKeyPress и т.п. нет возможности получить положение ячейки.

Comment: Положение ячейки я узнаю. KeyPress не получает значения нажатых кнопок когда активен ввод и поэтому я использую код который привел в вопросе, но так я получаю только нажатые кнопки, а пользователь может изменить текст разными способами.